# AIMP: how to ignore "the" and "a" in alphabetic sorting?

Tags: music-management, aimp

I just downloaded AIMP and I like it so far but in my music library the bands beginning with "the" are under T which I don't like. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following sort by template in the preferences:

```
%PrefixToTail(%Artist)
```

Then "The Who" will move behind "Westbam". ;-)

[image: Before]

[image: Preferences]

[image: After]